# aircrack-ng channel problem  under 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, networking, aircrack-ng

I would like to test security of my home wireless network, but I have lot of troubles with `aircrack-ng`.  I am using 12.04 LTS, `linux-3.2.0-27-generic-pae`. My wireless card is BCM4311 (14e4:4311).

Now `airodump` works fine, and packet\ injection too (`aireplay-ng -9 wlan0`), but when I want to send fake auth, I get this message

```
wlan0 is on channel 11, but the AP uses channel 7
```

I tried to set channel with `airmon` and iwconfig, but it didn't help. I don't use any network manager, I have read, that it sometimes causes troubles.

What can I do? Do I have to install some patches?

Answer (score 3):

When you run a scan using `airodump-ng mon0` and you try to inject some packets into the network you get this error.

So to fix it you should do the following :

```
airodump-ng mon0 -w anything  -c [channel number] -b [BSSID]
```

ex:

```
airodump-ng mon0 -c 6 -w  store_data_on_this_file -b 00:11:22:33:44:55
```

and then run `aireplay-ng` tool.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the command `-c 7` that makes the `wlan0` change the channel to 7, like this example:

```
airodump-ng -c "channel number" "monitor interface"
```

Comment: It works for `airodump-ng`, but not for `aireplay-ng`. `Aireplay` hasn't this option. In fact has, but it is for destination MAC address.

Comment: but it fixed your problem?

Comment: `airodump-ng` works fine. I have problems with `aireplay-ng`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to patch the compact-wireless package and rebuild:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
wget http://www.orbit-lab.org/kernel/compat-wireless-3-stable/v3.6/compat-wireless-3.6.2-1.tar.bz2
tar -jxf compat-wireless-3.6.2-1.tar.bz2
cd compat-wireless-3.6.2-1
wget http://patches.aircrack-ng.org/channel-negative-one-maxim.patch
sudo apt-get install patch
patch ./net/wireless/chan.c channel-negative-one-maxim.patch
make
sudo make install
sudo make unload
sudo reboot
```